# How to detect each Windows OS is used with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to check which version of windows is used in a remote machine, I'm using this command:

```
$version=[Environment]::OSVersion.Version | % {"{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $_.Major,$_.Minor,$_.Build}
```

I get the result for example windows 7 : 6.1.7600

but I found a problem :

Windows server 2012 R2 have : 6.1.9600

and windows 8.1 too : 6.1.9600

so I'm wondering if there is an other solution to get the version of windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another solution would be to get the caption via CIM. I think it's closest to what you want. It can be used to check local and Remote machines.

---

**Local:**

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Operatingsystem | Select-Object -expand Caption
```

Example Output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-CimInstance Win32_Operatingsystem | select -expand Caption
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
```

**Remote:**

Add the `-computername` parameter to `Get-CimInstance`

Example Output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-CimInstance Win32_Operatingsystem -ComputerName xy | select -expand Caption
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
```

---

Run `Get-CimInstance Win32_Operatingsystem | fl *` to see which properties you can additionally select to get the output you want.

Comment: thanks you very much sir!it's very useful.. i really appreciate your help

Comment: This method was deprecated with Windows 8.1.  See this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/25/use-powershell-to-find-operating-system-version/) for details.

Comment: Edited and changed `Get-WmiObject` to `Get-CimInstance`

Answer (score 1):

#### I'm wondering if there is an other solution to get the version of windows?

Use the following command to retrieve the full Version String (which includes the Name, Version, and Service Pack number:

```
[Environment]::OSVersion.VersionString
```

Example output:

```
PS F:\test> [Environment]::OSVersion.VersionString
Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
PS F:\test>
```